# Selenium: Multiple Test Suite files

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to run multiple Selenium suite files on Jenkins using Maven.

My First Suite file:

```
<suite
   name="First Automation Testing" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="20">
    <test name="First Test Case" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.mystore.automation.tests.FirstTest" />
           </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Second Suite file:

```
<suite
   name="Second Automation Testing" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="20">
    <test name="Second Test Case" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.mystore.automation.tests.SecondTest" />
           </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Third Suite file:

```
<suite
   name="Third Automation Testing" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="20">
    <test name="Third Test Case" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.mystore.automation.tests.ThirdTest" />
           </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And my Master/Complete Regression suite file

Regression-Suite.xml

```
<suite name="MyAutomation Testing for Checkout" parallel="tests" thread-count="20">
        <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="First-Suite.xml" />
        <suite-file path="Second-Suite.xml" />
        <suite-file path="Third-Suite.xml" />           
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Now when I execute the maven command to run the automation test Regression-Suite.xml I get the following error:

mvn clean integration-test -Dtest.suite=Regression-Suite.xml

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 50; columnNumber: 11; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:104)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 50; columnNumber: 11; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1395)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
    ... 13 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.203s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 15 06:04:41 PST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/691M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "qa-builds" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (integration-test) on project ASAnalyticsTests: There are test failures
```

.

The final resolved regression suite is:

```
<suite-files>
<suite
   name="First Automation Testing" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="20">
    <test name="First Test Case" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.mystore.automation.tests.FirstTest" />
           </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
    **<!-- This is the issue the xml here is mal-formed>**
    <test name="Second Test Case" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.mystore.automation.tests.SecondTest" />
           </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Third Test Case" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.mystore.automation.tests.ThirdTest" />
           </classes>
    </test>
</suite-files>
```

I know what is causing the issue but I don't know how to fix it any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)
```

Try to validate all your testng xml files (first,second, third and regression suite xmls) in an online validator say http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and execute scripts again.

**Edit:**

In case everything is every test suite is well formed, can you update maven surefire entries as given below:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/first-suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
         <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/second-suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
         <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/third-suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also refer sure-fire plugin documentation for configuring the test runs according to your needs: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: I don't think so, reason is if I execute the test suites (first second and third) individually the test runs successfully. The Issue is when you run try Regression-suite.xml file.

Comment: pls post your pom file snippet of surefire plugin

Comment: Okay I don't have any entries in my pom.xml for the test suites against the maven-surefire-plugin. Instead I give it while running command "mvn clean integration-test -Dtest.suite=Regression-Suite.xml" And reason being I don't want the entries hardcoded in the pom.xml so that it would allow me to execute different test suites by passing in as argument "-Dtest.suite"

Comment: @Shivakumar, understood your intention. still posting pom file snippet might help

Answer (score 0):

To me, this looks like a problem having the XML file encoded as UTF-16, which requires a BOM byte marker (an invisible character), but the marker is missing?  I would guess that if you make sure the testng.xml is a UTF-8 file, the problem should go away.

Also, you could try putting this at the top of your testng.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

Comment: Hello, All the xml files are UTF-8 and I tried adding doctype header in each of the xml files but still No luck!

Comment: @Shivakumar - You do notice the error in the XML that you posted in your question right?  The format seems to be wrong.  You are using the suite-files tag incorrectly: it only works with 'externally loaded' suite.xml files.